# What is the best way to decide if an image has alpha channel?

Tags: image, go, alpha

I need to decide if an image has alpha channel or not, so I write the code like this.

```
var HaveAlpha = func(Image image.Image) bool {
    switch Image.ColorModel() {
    case color.YCbCrModel, color.CMYKModel:
        return false
    case color.RGBAModel:
        return !Image.(*image.RGBA).Opaque()
    }
    // ...
    return false
}
```

So I need to list all the `ColorModel` types and use `Opaque()` to decide if the image has alpha channel or not (because I cannot use `Opaque()` method in type `image.Image` directly). And if an image has alpha channel but all pixels are opaque in the image (all RGBA of pixels in that image are like `(*,*,*,255)`), this code may return wrong answer.

Is there a right or better way to decide if an image has alpha channel or not in Golang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to check if the concrete value stored in the [`image.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) interface type has an `Opaque() bool` method, and if so, simply call that and return its result. Note that all concrete image types in the [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) package do have an `Opaque()` method, so this will cover most cases.

If the image does not have such an `Opaque()` method, loop over all pixels of the image and check if any of the pixel has an alpha value other than `0xff`, which means it's non-opaque.

Note that `Image.At()` has a return type of the general [`color.Color`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Color) interface type, which only guarantees a single method: `Color.RGBA()`. This `RGBA()` method returns the *alpha-premultiplied* red, green, blue and alpha components, so if a pixel has `0xff` alpha value, that equals to `0xffff` when "alpha-premultiplied", so that's what we need to compare to.

```
func Opaque(im image.Image) bool {
    // Check if image has Opaque() method:
    if oim, ok := im.(interface {
        Opaque() bool
    }); ok {
        return oim.Opaque() // It does, call it and return its result!
    }

    // No Opaque() method, we need to loop through all pixels and check manually:
    rect := im.Bounds()
    for y := rect.Min.Y; y < rect.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := rect.Min.X; x < rect.Max.X; x++ {
            if _, _, _, a := im.At(x, y).RGBA(); a != 0xffff {
                return false // Found a non-opaque pixel: image is non-opaque
            }
        }

    }
    return true // All pixels are opaque, so is the image
}
```

The above `Opaque()` function will return `true` if the image does not have an alpha channel, or it has but all pixels are opaque. It returns `false` if and only if the image has alpha channel and there is at least 1 pixel that is not (fully) opaque.

**Note:** If an image does have an `Opaque()` method, you can be sure that it takes existing pixels and their alpha values into consideration, so for example [`image.RGBA.Opaque()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RGBA.Opaque) also scans the entire image similarly to what we did above; but we had to do it in a general way, and `Opaque()` implementations of concrete images may be much more efficient (so it is highly recommended to use the "shipped" `Opaque()` method if it is available). As an example, implementation of [`image.YCbCr.Opaque()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RGBA.Opaque) is a simple `return true` statement because `YCbCr` images do not have alpha channel.

Comment: Opaque() method means all pixels alpha are 0xff return true, But use Opaque() to choose the image have alpha channel or not may have exception. If I have a png that have alpha channel and all the pixels are opaque. Or do not worry about this?

Comment: @YurinaShirahane The above `Opaque()` will return `true` if the image does not have an alpha channel, or it has but all pixels are opaque. It returns false if and only if the image has alpha channel and there is at least 1 pixel that is not (fully) opaque.

Comment: So Opaque() is:
true == "image does not have an alpha channel" or "image has an alpha channel but all pixels are opaque",
false == "image has an alpha channel and at least 1 pixel that is not (fully) opaque".
But I want to make a HaveAlpha(), that is:
true == image has an alpha channel no matter all pixels are opaque not,
false ==  image does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: !Opaque() can be used in HaveAlpha() that I want to make on "image does not have an alpha channel" and "image has an alpha channel and at least 1 pixel that is not (fully) opaque". But when "image has an alpha channel but all pixels are opaque", !Opaque() can not be used in HaveAlpha().

Comment: @YurinaShirahane The `image.Image` interface **does not enforce** all pixels to have the same `color.Color` concrete type. An `Image` implementation _may_ return `color.RGBA` for a pixel, and `color.Gray16` for another (since both implement `color.Color`).

Comment: I konw that. But now I only want to know is that how do I judge "a image that has an alpha channel and all pixels are opaque" that has an alpha channel or not. In this case, alpha channel of all pixels are 255 and Opaque() is true, this result is the same as a image that does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: @YurinaShirahane I'm not sure I understand you completely, but this is what my `Opaque()` function does.

Comment: I just tried if a png is 32bit, image.Image would *image.NRGBA, and 24bit and 8bit would be *image.RGBA, I think I could use both this and Opaque() to complete my  HaveAlpha() function. Thinks a lot on part "type assertion" and tell me what Opaque() does in all case. Or use NRGBA and RGBA to judge png-32bit (have alpha channel) and png-others-bit have any exception that I need to be careful?

Comment: Possible bug in the code above:

`for x := rect.Min.X; y < rect.Max.X; x++`

should be:

`for x := rect.Min.X; x < rect.Max.X; x++`